# Objective C - release blocks individually

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have the following dummy architecture: a singleton class that will receive some data, and, at some point(when returnCallback function is called), will return the data using a callback.

```
@interface Helper: NSObject
{
    void (^_completionHandler)(int someParameter);
}

+(Helper *)getInstance;

- (void) doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(int))handler;
@end


@implementation Helper

+(Helper *)getInstance {
    static Helper *instance = nil;

    @synchronized(self) {
        if (instance == nil)
            instance = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return instance;
}

- (void) doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(int))handler
{
    //do things 

    _completionHandler = [handler copy];

    //do things
}

-(void) returnCallback
{
    int result;
    //do things with result
    _completionHandler(result);
    //nothing to follow, it just returned the result.
}

@end
```

Untill now I was calling the helper a single time and everything worked ok. 
E.g.

```
[[Helper getInstance] doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^(int result){
    NSLog(@"I received %d", result);
}];
```

But now I need to call the helper 2 times, the second one being inside of the first one.
E.g.

```
[[Helper getInstance] doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^(int result){
    [[Helper getInstance] doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^(int result){
        NSLog(@" Yay, I'm good %d", result);
    }];


    NSLog(@"They stopped retaining me:( %d", result);
}];
```

The problem is(as displayed in the log) that the first function callback is released from memory and I cannot access the result variable. A way to resolve that is to keep 2 variables of the callbacks(one with the current one, one with the old one), but what if I'll need the 3rd one? I tried to build an NSMutableArray with the blocks references. But I had to remove them aswell, and I didn't figure out how.(they get copied inside Helper class, so I don't have a reference to that copied object inside the "Testing" class, do I?)

The above code isn't tested as this is more of an architecture-based question. I will however test it and edit the message asap if there are any errors.

Comment: Sounds like using a singleton is wrong in this case.

Comment: The singleton class is needed there for the //do things stuff unfortunately.

Comment: But it doesn't fit how you are using it. You require multiple instances each with unique completion handlers.  Why is it a singleton at all?

Comment: The helper class is using a queue to send some data synchronously via bluetooth and when I get an ACK from it, to return a success status via that block.

Comment: The singleton is needed for the synchronous part

Comment: it is a kinda bad architecture how your singleton class is dealing with blocks, as the block can be overridden by someone else before it literally invoked. I would prefer a more sophisticated way to store multiple blocks with some unique task identifier, and you can identify which of the blocks should be called back after a procedure is done.

Comment: I will wait for another opinions aswell(as I don't really mind changing architecture if it would be better), but this is a pretty straight-forward solution that improves my try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way you have it designed, you can only have one active operation. If you ever try to execute more operations than one at the time, unexpected stuff happens (as in your example).

There is an established pattern for doing stuff like this - take a look at `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`, e.g. [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift)

Comment: I will definitely check out that tutorial and try to understand the pattern described by NSOperation and NSOperationQueue, but can you be a little bit more specific regarding to this, until then?

Comment: I don't understand something related to this. Is the (^completionBlock)(void) method from NSOperation called after the operation is out of the queue, or is this method called when the operation is still in the queue and the operation be out when the block gets completed?

Comment: From class reference for `NSOperationQueue` "After being added to a queue, an operation remains in that queue until it is explicitly canceled or finishes executing its task. "

Comment: How can I make NSOperation's main method to wait for an event(like a bluetooth ACK)?

Comment: I don't think that discussing `NSOperation` further in comments is appropriate for SO. I suggest to open a new question if you struggle with something

Comment: Already did that after asking, sorry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372160/nsoperation-wait-for-event