# NSOperation wait for event

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation

I'd like to make a custom class that extends NSOperation in order to make successful communication with another device by bluetooth. The question I have is how can I implement the main method of the class so that it will wait for an event triggered by the bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use an infinite loop. It is not energy-efficient. As @lead_the_zeppelin said, use semaphore/mutex/etc. For example you may use `dispatch_group` functions like this:

```c
dispatch_group_t waitGroup = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_enter(waitGroup);
dispatch_async(otherQueue, ^{
    //long-running code
    dispatch_group_leave(waitGroup);
}
dispatch_group_wait(waitGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Answer (score -1):

What I did was just use continuous loop in a while until some event will trigger a BOOL to stop the loop. I don't know if this is safe, but it works.

```
while(!self.didFinish){
    ;
}
```

Comment: never use an infinite while loop. Use a semaphore or something similar.

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Comment: please look at Sega-Zero's solution to use group dispatch instead. [Read](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) more on dispatch queues.